# Manually Add the TortoiseSVN Registry information?

Tags: windows-registry, svn, tortoise-svn

I recently installed TortoiseSVN on my Windows 7 64 bit computer. For reasons outside the scope of this question, the installer could not get appropriate permissions to add the keys that TSVN needs in the registry.

I'd like to add those keys manually, with a reg file. I tried unzipping the .msi installer to see if the .reg file was there, but no luck. I looked around the net a little, but no luck. I looked in the source code, figuring there must be a file in there somewhere with a list of all the registry changes in one place, but I haven't found any such thing.

How can I get a complete list of registry changes for a fresh TortoiseSVN installation?

Comment: I did find: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#XJa9F1p-bAg/trunk/src/TortoiseSVNSetup/StructureFragment.wxs&q=hklm%20package:http://tortoisesvn%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=737 and http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#XJa9F1p-bAg/trunk/src/TortoiseSVNSetup/SubWCRev.wxs&q=hklm%20package:http://tortoisesvn%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=16&ct=rc which both  have keys, but I don't know if it's ALL keys, and they aren't in a usable format for me. It occurs to me that someone who has a fresh install on a 64 bit system could probably just export the registry directory, and send it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked about this [three years ago](http://groups.google.com/group/tortoisesvn/browse_thread/thread/25246ca1340f6032) and Stefan was quite insistent on using the installer and not providing a way to install manually (that was before portable software really took off).

That said, it was simple enough to monitor and capture the actions of the installer to create a manual (un)installation with a few simple `.REG` files.

I ran a sandboxed copy of Windows (XP SP2) in a VM and ran PC Magazine’s [InCtrl 5](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.pcmag.com%2Farticle2%2F0%2C2817%2C25198%2C00.asp&ei=g3NwTbPtHsT2gAeAjp1N&usg=AFQjCNH8anYprHeaKbIY4RmZZazk-x35kw&sig2=jUD4jVV0akJF3IrxKsQwJA) to monitor the differences from before and after the installation, then went through the logs to narrow down the changes related to the TortoiseSVN installer and weed out any cruft.

I’ll post them in order of ascending length; make sure to adjust the paths accordingly. (You’ll also want to make sure to add the TortoiseSVN path directory to your `path`.)

---

**Tools.reg**

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN\DiffTools]
".doc"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\diff-doc.js\" %base %mine //E:javascript"
".docx"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\diff-docx.js\" %base %mine //E:javascript"
".nb"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\diff-nb.vbs\" %base %mine //E:vbscript"
".ods"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\diff-ods.vbs\" %base %mine //E:vbscript"
".odt"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\diff-odt.vbs\" %base %mine //E:vbscript"
".ppt"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\diff-ppt.js\" %base %mine //E:javascript"
".pptx"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\diff-pptx.js\" %base %mine //E:javascript"
".sxw"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\diff-sxw.vbs\" %base %mine //E:vbscript"
".xls"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\diff-xls.vbs\" %base %mine //E:vbscript"
".xlsx"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\diff-xlsx.vbs\" %base %mine //E:vbscript"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN\MergeTools]
".doc"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\merge-doc.js\" %merged %theirs %mine %base //E:javascript"
".docx"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\merge-docx.js\" %merged %theirs %mine %base //E:javascript"
".ods"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\merge-ods.vbs\" %merged %theirs %mine %base //E:vbscript"
".odt"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\merge-odt.vbs\" %merged %theirs %mine %base //E:vbscript"
".sxw"="wscript.exe \"C:\\TortoiseSVN\\Diff-Scripts\\merge-sxw.vbs\" %merged %theirs %mine %base //E:vbscript"
```

---

**Uninstall.reg**

```
REGEDIT4

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryLocation\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.diff]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.patch]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351346-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351347-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351348-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134A-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134B-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134C-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134D-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134E-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134F-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351350-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994560-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994561-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994562-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994563-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994564-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994565-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994566-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994567-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994568-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F26E2640-0CFF-43DC-8325-575A3261D885}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\CopyHookHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\DragDropHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ColumnHandlers\{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\DragDropHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{2F5EA5B0-4DE7-4f96-8E6B-FC0C37D9C0D6}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SubWCRev.object.1]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SubWCRev.object]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\svn+ssh]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\svn]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tsvn]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{40ACF49D-74FF-4165-94E9-0E002C448520}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\unified_diff_file]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\1TortoiseNormal]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\2TortoiseModified]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\3TortoiseConflict]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\4TortoiseLocked]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\5TortoiseReadOnly]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\6TortoiseDeleted]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\7TortoiseAdded]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\8TortoiseIgnored]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\9TortoiseUnversioned]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\Offline Files]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Approved]
"{30351348-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"=-
"{30351347-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"=-
"{3035134A-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"=-
"{3035134C-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"=-
"{30351346-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"=-
"{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"=-
"{3035134B-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"=-
"{3035134D-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"=-
"{3035134E-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"=-
"{3035134F-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"=-
"{30351350-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"=-
"{C5994560-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"=-
"{C5994561-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"=-
"{C5994562-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"=-
"{C5994563-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"=-
"{C5994564-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"=-
"{C5994565-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"=-
"{C5994566-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"=-
"{C5994567-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"=-
"{C5994568-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"=-
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\SubWCRev.exe]
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseSVN]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays]
```

---

**Install.reg**

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryLocation\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.diff]
@="unified_diff_file"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.patch]
@="unified_diff_file"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351346-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351346-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseStub.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351346-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\shellex\NoRecentDocs]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351347-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351347-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseStub.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351347-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\shellex\NoRecentDocs]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351348-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351348-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\InProcServer32]
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseStub.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351348-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\shellex\NoRecentDocs]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\InProcServer32]
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseStub.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\shellex\NoRecentDocs]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134A-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134A-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\InProcServer32]
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseStub.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134A-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\shellex\NoRecentDocs]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134B-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134B-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseStub.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134B-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\shellex\NoRecentDocs]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134C-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134C-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseStub.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134C-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\shellex\NoRecentDocs]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134D-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134D-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseStub.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134D-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\shellex\NoRecentDocs]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134E-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134E-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseStub.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134E-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\shellex\NoRecentDocs]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134F-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134F-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\InProcServer32]
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseStub.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3035134F-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\shellex\NoRecentDocs]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351350-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351350-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\InProcServer32]
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseStub.dll"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{30351350-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}\shellex\NoRecentDocs]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994560-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994560-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\TortoiseOverlays.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994561-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994561-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\TortoiseOverlays.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994562-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994562-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\TortoiseOverlays.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994563-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994563-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\TortoiseOverlays.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994564-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994564-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\TortoiseOverlays.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994565-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994565-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\TortoiseOverlays.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994566-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994566-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\TortoiseOverlays.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994567-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994567-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\TortoiseOverlays.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994568-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}]
@="TortoiseSVN"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{C5994568-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\TortoiseOverlays.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F26E2640-0CFF-43DC-8325-575A3261D885}]
@="SubWCRev Server Object"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F26E2640-0CFF-43DC-8325-575A3261D885}\LocalServer32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\SubWCRevCOM.exe /automation"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F26E2640-0CFF-43DC-8325-575A3261D885}\ProgID]
@="SubWCRev.object.1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F26E2640-0CFF-43DC-8325-575A3261D885}\TypeLib]
@="{40ACF49D-74FF-4165-94E9-0E002C448520}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{F26E2640-0CFF-43DC-8325-575A3261D885}\VersionIndependentProgID]
@="SubWCRev.object"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\CopyHookHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\DragDropHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{3035134A-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ColumnHandlers\{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\DragDropHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{3035134A-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{2F5EA5B0-4DE7-4f96-8E6B-FC0C37D9C0D6}]
@="ISubWCRev"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{2F5EA5B0-4DE7-4f96-8E6B-FC0C37D9C0D6}\ProxyStubClsid]
@="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{2F5EA5B0-4DE7-4f96-8E6B-FC0C37D9C0D6}\ProxyStubClsid32]
@="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Interface\{2F5EA5B0-4DE7-4f96-8E6B-FC0C37D9C0D6}\TypeLib]
@="{40ACF49D-74FF-4165-94E9-0E002C448520}"
"Version"="1.0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\TortoiseSVN]
@="{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SubWCRev.object.1]
@="SubWCRev Server Object"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SubWCRev.object.1\CLSID]
@="{F26E2640-0CFF-43DC-8325-575A3261D885}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SubWCRev.object]
@="SubWCRev Server Object"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SubWCRev.object\CLSID]
@="{F26E2640-0CFF-43DC-8325-575A3261D885}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SubWCRev.object\CurVer]
@="SubWCRev.object.1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\svn+ssh]
@="URL:SVN+SSH Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\svn+ssh\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseProc.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\svn+ssh\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseProc.exe /command:repobrowser /path:\"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\svn]
@="URL:SVN Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\svn\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseProc.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\svn\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseProc.exe /command:repobrowser /path:\"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tsvn]
@="URL:TSVN Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tsvn\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseProc.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\tsvn\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseProc.exe /command:checkout /url:\"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{40ACF49D-74FF-4165-94E9-0E002C448520}\1.0]
@="LibSubWCRev"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{40ACF49D-74FF-4165-94E9-0E002C448520}\1.0\0\win32]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\SubWCRevCOM.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{40ACF49D-74FF-4165-94E9-0E002C448520}\FLAGS]
@="0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{40ACF49D-74FF-4165-94E9-0E002C448520}\HELPDIR]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\unified_diff_file\shell\open\command]
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseUDiff.exe /patchfile:\"%1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN]
"SoundUtils KeyPath"="keypath"
"TortoiseSVN"="TortoiseSVN"
"TortoiseMerge"="TortoiseMerge"
"TortoiseIDiff"="TortoiseIDiff"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\SubWCRev.exe]
"Path"="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin"
@="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\SubWCRev.exe"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\1TortoiseNormal]
@="{C5994560-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\2TortoiseModified]
@="{C5994561-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\3TortoiseConflict]
@="{C5994562-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\4TortoiseLocked]
@="{C5994563-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\5TortoiseReadOnly]
@="{C5994564-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\6TortoiseDeleted]
@="{C5994565-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\7TortoiseAdded]
@="{C5994566-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\8TortoiseIgnored]
@="{C5994567-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\9TortoiseUnversioned]
@="{C5994568-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\Offline Files]
@="{750fdf0e-2a26-11d1-a3ea-080036587f03}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Approved]
"{30351348-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"="TortoiseSVN"
"{30351347-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"="TortoiseSVN"
"{3035134A-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"="TortoiseSVN"
"{3035134C-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"="TortoiseSVN"
"{30351346-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"="TortoiseSVN"
"{30351349-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"="TortoiseSVN"
"{3035134B-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"="TortoiseSVN"
"{3035134D-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"="TortoiseSVN"
"{3035134E-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"="TortoiseSVN"
"{3035134F-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"="TortoiseSVN"
"{30351350-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"="TortoiseSVN"
"{C5994560-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"="TortoiseOverlays"
"{C5994561-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"="TortoiseOverlays"
"{C5994562-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"="TortoiseOverlays"
"{C5994563-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"="TortoiseOverlays"
"{C5994564-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"="TortoiseOverlays"
"{C5994565-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"="TortoiseOverlays"
"{C5994566-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"="TortoiseOverlays"
"{C5994567-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"="TortoiseOverlays"
"{C5994568-53D9-4125-87C9-F193FC689CB2}"="TortoiseOverlays"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays]
"NormalIcon"="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\icons\\XPStyle\\NormalIcon.ico"
"ModifiedIcon"="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\icons\\XPStyle\\ModifiedIcon.ico"
"ConflictIcon"="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\icons\\XPStyle\\ConflictIcon.ico"
"DeletedIcon"="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\icons\\XPStyle\\DeletedIcon.ico"
"ReadOnlyIcon"="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\icons\\XPStyle\\ReadOnlyIcon.ico"
"LockedIcon"="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\icons\\XPStyle\\LockedIcon.ico"
"AddedIcon"="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\icons\\XPStyle\\AddedIcon.ico"
"IgnoredIcon"="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\icons\\XPStyle\\IgnoredIcon.ico"
"UnversionedIcon"="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\TortoiseOverlays\\icons\\XPStyle\\UnversionedIcon.ico"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Added]
"SVN"="{3035134E-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Conflict]
"SVN"="{30351348-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Deleted]
"SVN"="{3035134C-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Ignored]
"SVN"="{3035134F-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Locked]
"SVN"="{3035134D-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Modified]
"SVN"="{30351347-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Normal]
"SVN"="{30351346-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\ReadOnly]
"SVN"="{3035134B-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Unversioned]
"SVN"="{30351350-7B7D-4FCC-81B4-1E394CA267EB}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseSVN]
"ProcPath"="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseProc.exe"
"CachePath"="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TSVNCache.exe"
"TMergePath"="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoiseMerge.exe"
"Directory"="C:\\TortoiseSVN\\"
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Edit `install.reg` ([from Synetechs answer](https://superuser.com/questions/250260/manually-add-the-tortoisesvn-registry-information/253082#253082)) by replacing all

```
    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
```

with

```
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes
```

and you have just created registry for your very own portable TortoiseSVN.

Now import it into registry (should succeed even without admin rights) and restart. TortoiseSVN context menus should be visible.